# Azure AppService ARM Complete Deployment - how to remove existing hostNameBinding?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

I am using 'New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Mode Complete' to deploy an Azure AppService with a custom domain.

the ARM template defines a custom hostNameBinding

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/hostNameBindings",
    "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('appServiceName'), '/myCustomDomain.com')]",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('appServiceName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "siteName": "[parameters('appServiceName')]",
        "hostNameType": "Verified"
    }
}
```

and the myCustomDomain.com is added as expected.

when I remove the hostNameBinding from the ARM template and 'New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Mode Complete' the hostNameBinding is **not** removed.

---

Resetting the hostNameBinding via PowerShell

```
Set-AzureRmWebApp -Name "..." -ResourceGroupName "..." -HostNames @("<placeHolder>.azurewebsites.net")
```

works as long as the ".azurewebsites.net" domain is used.

---

I therefore added this hostNameBinding to the ARM template

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/hostNameBindings",
    "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('appServiceName'), '/', parameters('appServiceName'), '.azurewebsites.net')]",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('appServiceName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "siteName": "[parameters('appServiceName')]",
        "hostNameType": "Verified"
    }
}
```

but the myCustomDomain.com is not removed from the Azure AppService Hostnames property.

How can I define the list of custom domain names within the ARM template to 'sync' this to an Azure AppService?

Any hints how to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, as far as I'm concerned. Refer to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/overview#resource-groups),  You can only update by Redeploy this template you updated rather than 'sync':

> All the resources in your resource group should share the same
> lifecycle. You deploy, **update**, and delete them together.

There are some ways you can update your custom domain, but you can **not** do it 'sync' with ARM templates.

If you want to change your custom domain in portal, go to your **App service**, and navigate to **custom domain** page, and follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain).

If you want to change it by CLI command line, you can follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#automate-with-scripts).

Comment: my definition of 'sync' in the context of  'New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Mode Complete' ;) .... if a property is defined within the ARM template, the value(s) of the property are reflected in Azure resources

Comment: Can you share how you use `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Mode Complete`? Is it `New-AzManagementGroupDeployment -Location <location> -TemplateFile <path-to-template>`?